# Error in vshost32-clr2.exe while invoking C written DLL into C#

Tags: c#, delegates, dllimport, calling-convention

I'm trying to use a C written DLL (FlyCapture API, from Point Grey Research Inc) in a C# code, but I always get a runtime error. Here I have two samples of code using the DLL: one is written in C++, and in the other I tried to do exactly the same thing in C# using an unsafe context.

C++ code:

```
void Callback(void* Param, int Message, unsigned long lParam)
{
    cout << Message << "\t" << lParam << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *context;
    FlyCaptureCallback *callback = Callback;

    flycaptureCreateContext(&context);
    flycaptureModifyCallback(context, callback, NULL, true);

    _sleep(5000);

    flycaptureModifyCallback(context, callback, NULL, false);
    flycaptureDestroyContext(context);

    return 0;
}
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("pgrflycapture.dll")]
static extern int flycaptureCreateContext(void** pContext);

[DllImport("pgrflycapture.dll")]
static extern int flycaptureDestroyContext(void* context);

[DllImport("pgrflycapture.dll")]
static extern int flycaptureModifyCallback(void* context, IntPtr pfnCallback, void* pParam, bool bAdd);

delegate void FlyCaptureCallback(void* Param, int Message, uint lParam);

static void Callback(void* Param, int Message, uint lParam)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Message.ToString() + "\t" + lParam.ToString());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    void *context;
    IntPtr callback = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((FlyCaptureCallback) Callback);

    flycaptureCreateContext(&context);
    flycaptureModifyCallback(context, callback, null, true);

    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    flycaptureModifyCallback(context, callback, null, false);
    flycaptureDestroyContext(context);
}
```

The purpose of this program is to register a callback function so that when an event occurs in a camera bus, this function is called. The program then waits for 5 seconds and removes the callback from the register. The C++ application works fine, if I remove the camera from the computer during those 5 seconds, a message appears in the console. The C# application, in other hand, only works fine when no event occurs, hence the callback function is not called. If I try to remove the camera from the computer, the Callback function is successfully called and the right numbers appear in the screen, but Windows displays a message saying that "vshost32-clr2.exe has stopped working" during the function flycaptureDestroyContext.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact runtime error that you get?

Comment: Go to the FlyCapture samples page and view the samples. http://www.ptgrey.com/products/pgrflycapture/samples.asp

Comment: It looks like Point Grey has a C# SDK.  Is there a particular reason you are not using that?  Regardless, if you are seeing odd behavior around a callback from native code, make sure your calling conventions are right: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/01/18/p-invoke-stack-imbalance-mda.aspx

Comment: The error's Problem Event Name is BEX (Buffer Overflow Exception). About the samples, I have them in my computer, but none of them contains examples of flycaptureModifyCallback in C#. Besides, the program in C++ is working fine, so I think I'm not translating it correctly to C#.

Comment: I didn't know about this C# SDK, but I haven't payed attention to the calling conventions. I'll take a look at it, thank you very much!

Comment: The problem is most likely that your `DllImport` statements are incorrect. The SDK will have those already created in a library that you can just include (`using FlyCapture2Managed;`) Otherwise you'll need to get the C/C++ header files and translate the prototypes. If you want help translating those prototypes then you'll have to show them to us.

Comment: Yes, I should have considered the calling convention in the DllImport statements. Now I have a lead to follow, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it! The problem was that the functions of the API (flycaptureCreateContext, flycaptureModifyCallback and flycaptureDestroyContext) were declared in the C headers as __cdecl, but I haven't considered it in the DllImport statements. There follows corrected C# code:

```
[DllImport("pgrflycapture.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int flycaptureCreateContext(void** pContext);

[DllImport("pgrflycapture.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int flycaptureDestroyContext(void* context);

[DllImport("pgrflycapture.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int flycaptureModifyCallback(void* context, FlyCaptureCallback pfnCallback, void* pParam, bool bAdd);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void FlyCaptureCallback(void* Param, int Message, uint lParam);

static void Callback(void* Param, int Message, uint lParam)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Message.ToString() + "\t" + lParam.ToString());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    void *context;
    FlyCaptureCallback callback = (FlyCaptureCallback) Callback;

    flycaptureCreateContext(&context);
    flycaptureModifyCallback(context, callback, null, true);

    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    flycaptureModifyCallback(context, callback, null, false);
    flycaptureDestroyContext(context);
}
```

Thanks lnmx and Jim Mischel for your valuable help!